# Plot part of a contour curve of the imaginary part of a complex function

Tags: plotting, conditional

I want to plot some contour cuvres of a simple function $f(z)=((z + 1/z)^2 - 4)*(1 - I)$.

The code `ComplexContourPlot[Im[((z + 1/z)^2 - 4)*(1 - I)] == 0, {z, 2}]` generates a nice curve $\Im[f(z)]=0$, see the figure attached.

Now I want to plot the part of the curve $\Im[f(z)]=0$ with $\Re[f(z)]>0$. I couldn't figure out how to realize this condition when plotting. Thanks in advance.

[image: Plot of Im=0.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`RegionFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionFunction.html)

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[z_] := ((z + 1/z)^2 - 4)*(1 - I)

Legended[
 Show[
  ComplexContourPlot[Im[f[z]] == 0, {z, 2},
   ContourStyle -> Red,
   RegionFunction -> Function[{z, func}, 0 < Re[f[z]]],
   PlotPoints -> 75],
  ComplexContourPlot[Im[f[z]] == 0, {z, 2},
   ContourStyle -> Blue,
   RegionFunction -> Function[{z, func}, Re[f[z]] <= 0],
   PlotPoints -> 75]],
 Placed[LineLegend[{Red, Blue},
   {"Re(f(z))>0", "Re(f(z))≤0"}], {.7, .8}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. This is beautiful. In your RegionFunction, you used two variables {z, func}. It appears that one variable {z} also does the job. Could you explain why you picked those two variables instead of one?

Comment: There are two variables available. Since you only want to use the first, you can specify either one or two. It is just personal preference in that situation.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: If brevity is important you could also use `Legended[Show[ComplexContourPlot[Im[f[z]] == 0, {z, 2}, ContourStyle -> #[[2]], RegionFunction -> #[[1]], PlotPoints -> 75] & /@{{0 < Re[f[#]] &, Red}, {Re[f[#]] <= 0 &, Blue}}], Placed[LineLegend[{Red, Blue}, {"Re(f(z))>0", "Re(f(z))\[LessEqual]0"}], {.7, .8}]]`